# $ajax con POST a un .php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Tengo un componente en Javascript que antes me creaba un archivo para que el usuario lo guarde. Ahora estoy cambiando esa funcionalidad para que se guarde al pulsar el botón, pero que lo haga en el servidor. Para ello debo emplear código que no sea de la parte del cliente, y estoy haciéndolo con AJAX. En la función del botón tengo definida la función AJAX así:

```
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "hola.php",
            data: data,
            // contentType: "text/plain"
        })  
            .done (function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                alert("Guardado correctamente" + jqXHR + data +textStatus );    
            })
            .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("La solicitud ha fallado: " + textStatus + errorThrown);
            });
```

El php lo que hace es guardar el contenido de la variable que le paso en un fichero con un `fwrite` el php sí que se ejecuta bien, pero el problema lo tengo en que no me llega la variable bien, por supuesto hago el `$data = $_POST['data'];`

**EDIT:**
Vale, me he dado cuenta que la variable data si la paso así: {"data" : data} sí que se envía bien... no sé...

Comment: Pero ¿qué estás enviando en la variable `data`?  ¿Qué muestra un `console.log(data);`?

Comment: y con la funcion success ? que te imprime la data ?

Comment: Te recomiendo usar los metodos shorthard de jQuery `$.post({...` para limpieza del código, pero para solucionar tu duda necesitas proveer mas información.

Comment: la variable data lleva un string de los datos, supongo será un string.
Con la función succes es lo mismo que con la .done, no?
Es más eficiente el $.post que como lo tengo yo?

Comment: Puedes pasar data de esta manera data: {data} igualmente funcionara.